# i can't associate a different modal windows with different objects

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

For several days I can't find the right solution.. I can't associate my different objects with different modal windows. Maybe someone could look at my code  and suggest something? I even tried to link everything separately, but that doesn't work either.

I'm still learning javaScript, which is probably obvious, but I've been looking for a solution for a long time now and you are my last hope

This is cards code (there are 3 more):

```
    <div class="cards_grid">
<!--1-->
          <div class="cards">
            <img src="foto/20210218_135910.jpg" alt="Mercedes" style="width:100%">
            <h1>Mercedes</h1>
            <p class="price">€9.999</p>
            <p>⚙ Vienatūris ⚙ 2010 ⚙ Dyzelinas ⚙ Automatas ⚙ Rida: 130.000</p>
            <p><button data-modal="modal1" class="open_modal">Suzinoti daugiau</button></p>
          </div>
<!--modal 1-->
<div class="modal hidden" id="modal1">
  <button class="close_modal">&#x2715</button>
  <div class="modal_content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius laboriosam, illo facilis saepe, unde incidunt suscipit officia eligendi quas, quos repudiandae nihil dicta quae non minus exercitationem ab numquam! Sunt!</p>
    <img src="foto/20210218_135910.jpg" alt="Mercedes" style="width:100%">
    <img src="foto/20210218_135910.jpg" alt="Mercedes" style="width:100%">
    <img src="foto/20210218_135910.jpg" alt="Mercedes" style="width:100%">
    <img src="foto/20210218_135910.jpg" alt="Mercedes" style="width:100%">
    <img src="foto/20210218_135910.jpg" alt="Mercedes" style="width:100%">
    <button class="modal_btn">SUSISIEKIME</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay hidden"></div>

<!--2-->
<div class="cards">
            <img src="foto/20210322_100211.jpg" alt="BMW" style="width:100%">
            <h1>BMW</h1>
            <p class="price">€9.999</p>
            <p>⚙ Vienatūris ⚙ 2010 ⚙ Dyzelinas ⚙ Automatas ⚙ Rida: 130.000</p>
            <p><button data-modal="modal2" class="open_modal">Suzinoti daugiau</button></p>
</div>
<!--modal 2-->
          <div class="modal hidden" id="modal2">
            <button class="close_modal">&#x2715</button>
            <div class="modal_content">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius laboriosam, illo facilis saepe, unde incidunt suscipit officia eligendi quas, quos repudiandae nihil dicta quae non minus exercitationem ab numquam! Sunt!</p>
              <img src="foto/20210322_100211.jpg" alt="BMW" style="width:100%">
              <img src="foto/20210322_100211.jpg" alt="BMW" style="width:100%">
              <img src="foto/20210322_100211.jpg" alt="BMW" style="width:100%">
              <img src="foto/20210322_100211.jpg" alt="BMW" style="width:100%">
              <img src="foto/20210322_100211.jpg" alt="BMW" style="width:100%">
              <button class="modal_btn">SUSISIEKIME</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector(".close_modal");
const btnOpenModal = document.querySelectorAll(".open_modal");

const openModal = function () {
  modal.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
};

const closeModal = function () {
  modal.classList.add("hidden");
  overlay.classList.add("hidden");
};

for (let i = 0; i < btnOpenModal.length; i++)
  btnOpenModal[i].addEventListener("click", openModal1);

btnCloseModal.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
overlay.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Escape") {
    if (!modal.classList.contains("hidden")) {
      closeModal();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and why and how to make [mre]. You can not expect people to go browse your entire GitHub repository. That is not how SO work, you need to share code here. And you haven't specify where the problem is, not in lines, not in files, not in elements. Be specific and use `<>` button in here in editor to make a snippet.

Comment: document.querySelector(".modal") will return single modal instance of first occurrence thus it's always showing same modal. I've slightly modified your code and committed to your repo.

Comment: I'm very thankfull! and even more thanks for the explanation, it really helps me to improve :)